# Include other apps when creating a Site collection using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have created a color theme provider hosted apps which includes an app part.

Now I am creating another provider hosted apps, which creates a site collection using CSOM. I want to make sure the color theme app is included on the news site collections created by my app by default.